# NativeScript navigate to another page from custom Android activity

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing an APP with wechat login feature. After getting approval from wechat it will call a custom activity of my NativeScript APP. I am getting response correctly but how can I move to another page instated of the home page after doing some verification. I am using NativeScript + Angular.

[Sample code](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-wechat-login-sample/blob/b94eec6c8d954ab4e76247d3361abf823b002abb/src/app/wxapi.WXEntryActivity.android.ts#L44)

```
getJSON("https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/oauth2/access_token?appid=ID&secret=SECRET&code=" + res.code + "&grant_type=authorization_code").then((res) => {
    console.dir(res);
    // ===> here I want navigation
}, err => {
    console.dir(err);
})
```

I tried like this:

```
frame.topmost().navigate("src/app/login/login.component");
```

but getting error:

> JS: Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot set property '_moduleName' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property '_moduleName' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property '_moduleName' of undefined

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are using Angular, use your [RouterExtension](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation) to navigate.

Comment: If your issue is about getting the reference to `RouterExtensions` instance from the custom activity, you may simply fire an event on application module from the custom activity (similar to other global events like pause, resume etc.,) and listen to the same from your Angular component (may be app component) where you will can inject and get access to `RouterExtensions` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Manoj. I tried to use `RouterExtensions` directly in custom activity but didn't get success. Will you please give some example/sample code regarding `event` as you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire an event from the Activity callback, something like

```
import { android } from "tns-core-modules/application";

...

public onResp(res: com.tencent.mm.opensdk.modelbase.BaseResp) {
    console.log("onResp");
    console.dir(res);
    androidApp.notify(<AndroidActivityEventData>{ eventName: 'wxapiresponse', object: android, activity: this });
}
```

In app component, listen to the event

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      application.android.on('wxapiresponse', this.wxApiResponse, this);
    }

    wxApiResponse() {
       // making sure the event callback runs inside Angular zone
       this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.routerExtensions.navigate(...);
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your code but it's not navigating the page. It's remain in same page :(

Comment: I tried with `setTimeout` too but still no luck :( . Event was firing correctly but not navigating :(

Comment: If I'll use`setTimeout` in `onResp` method then it's working. Thank you so much! ```setTimeout(() => {
            androidApp.notify(<AndroidActivityEventData>{
                eventName: 'wxapiresponse',
                object: res,
                activity: this
            });
        }, 1000);```

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem cost me an entire Weekend, without knowing how the companion controller **`.js` or `.ts`** files look like I can only recommend you go to the basics / source:

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#frame

it helped me find the problem in my code.

If you wrote a custom Page that does not start from a **`template`** chances are you wrote the controller too and it's easy to overlook some line that is present in the samples - even thou it looks like you don't need it.

If you paste your controller JS we could understand your context.

For instance, here is piece of code you should definitely include to help you debug:

in your **`page-you-navigate-to.xml`**

```
<Page loaded="onPageLoaded" class="page">
...
</Page>
```

in your **`page-you-navigate-to.ts`**

```
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

export function onPageLoaded(args: EventData): void {
    const page = <Page>args.object;
    var context = page.navigationContext;
    page.bindingContext = context;
    console.log("Target page Loaded.");
}
```

Start your debugger, and step through see where you have `null` values and read up on those method calls and their parameters.

Comment: FYI, You will not deal with Page / Frame directly in Angular, it's taken care by Router.